# Manim - BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to setup Manim on a Linux Mint Xfce computer. Whenever I try to execute:

```
manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl
```

I get this error:

```
Media will be written to ./media/. You can change this behavior with the --media_dir flag.
Unknown input format: 'rawvideo'
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myzel394/PycharmProjects/manimtest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/manimlib/extract_scene.py", line 155, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File "/home/myzel394/PycharmProjects/manimtest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.construct()
  File "example_scenes.py", line 83, in construct
    self.play(ShowCreation(square))
  File "/home/myzel394/PycharmProjects/manimtest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 848, in wrapper
    func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myzel394/PycharmProjects/manimtest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 944, in play
    self.progress_through_animations(animations)
  File "/home/myzel394/PycharmProjects/manimtest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 901, in progress_through_animations
    self.add_frames(self.get_frame())
  File "/home/myzel394/PycharmProjects/manimtest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/manimlib/scene/scene.py", line 1135, in add_frames
    self.file_writer.write_frame(frame)
  File "/home/myzel394/PycharmProjects/manimtest/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/manimlib/scene/scene_file_writer.py", line 336, in write_frame
    self.writing_process.stdin.write(frame.tostring())
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I tried following https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/669 but nothing helped. I upgraded ffmpeg and all my other stuff but I still get the same error.

What should I do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to check if the upgraded ffmpeg is working properly, and if it is, see if the problem is due to a combination of ffmpeg and manim versions.

I got the same error.
Then I checked the cause,
The `ffmpeg` command was not working properly.
Finally, I reinstalled `ffmpeg` and the problem was solved!

In my case,
It is working correctly with each of the following version combinations;

ffmpeg           :5.1.2
Manim Community  :v0.16.0.post0
MacOS            :13.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I uninstalled `ffmpeg@6` and installed `ffmpeg@5` because this is an alternate version I had to add the following to the path using the terminal.

```bash
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg@5/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

For compilers to find `ffmpeg@5` I set the following using the rerminal

```bash
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg@5/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg@5/include"
```

For `pkg-config` to find `ffmpeg@5` I set the following:

```bash
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg@5/lib/pkgconfig"
```

My macOS is 13.5.2 (22G91)